# neo4j auto-index item corrupted or orphaned

Tags: neo4j

I somehow deleted a node without the auto index entry updating.  Now when I do a query for the missing node using the auto-index

```
node:index:node_auto_index:uname:test
```

I get the following error:

```
Node[19220] not found. This can be because someone else deleted this entity while we were trying to read properties from it, or because of concurrent modification of other properties on this entity. The problem should be temporary.
```

How do I clean up the index to flush the orphaned index entry and also prevent this from happening in the production database

Comment: mayber restarting the instance will help in manner of auto indexing.

Comment: it would but how can I recover without rebooting, since I can't reboot the production server

Comment: was your auto-index disabled? Can you describe how it came to that? 
The node is normally deleted lazily from the index. Do you get the error repeatedly or only once? Can you perhaps share a full stack trace?

Comment: it got corrupted while I was running my unit tests several times in a row, creating, deleting a node with the same properties.  The error continues and doesn't lazily get cleaned up, I've tested it over the course of hours.  That same error is also shown from the admin control panel when entering the query in the cypher tool as well as in the object explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW This issue has been fixed, so that the entities will be automatically removed from the auto index when deleted. 1.9 will contain this fix.

Comment: is that fix in the current 1.9 m1 milestone?